# getting blurred image thumbnails displayed on shaka player?

Tags: jsdoc, shaka

I'm using shaka player latest version to as a player in my app. I'm trying to display the thumbnail images while seeking on the player progress bar. But when I seek forward/rewind on the player progress bar the thumbnails that are getting displayed are blurred even though the content is being played in High Resolution without any delay.

Is there any configuration that has to be done to display proper images instead of blurred images while scrubbing.

Thanks and happy coding.